# Check if folder is there, if not create it on current user logged in VBS

Tags: vbscript, createobject, create-directory

Currently this is my script

```
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' Get the %userprofile% in a variable, or else it won't be recognized
userProfile = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%userprofile%" )
```

What I am trying to do is grab the current user logged in, I want it to check the directory D:\"personsuser"\Appdata\Roaming\Local to see if the folder "Local" is created, if it isn't created I want to create one via createobject in vbs. The script above from what i know grabs the current logged on user, however i'm not sure how to use this variable to create a folder.

I know i will have to incorporate something along these lines:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\FSO")
```

And or something along these lines:

```
Dim objNetwork
Dim userName
Dim FSO

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
userName = objNetwork.userName

If fso.driveExists("D:\" & userName & "\AppData\Local\") Then
    FSO.CreateDirectory ("D:\" & userName & "\AppData\Local\")
End If
```

Thanks in advance, not very familiar with VBS however that is the only platform I can operate from in the environment that i'm using it.

Comment: The `Local` subfolder in the user profile should be created automatically. If it isn't, you should investigate what's preventing its creation and fix that.

Answer (score 22):

```
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' Get the %userprofile% in a variable, or else it won't be recognized
userProfile = oWS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%userprofile%" )

Dim objNetwork
Dim userName
Dim FSO
Dim Folder

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
userName = objNetwork.userName

If NOT (FSO.FolderExists(userProfile + "\AppData\Roaming\Local")) Then
    ' Delete this if you don't want the MsgBox to show
    MsgBox("Local folder doesn't exists, creating...")
    splitString = Split(userProfile, "\")

    ' Create folder
    MsgBox("D:\" + splitString(2) + "\AppData\Roaming\Local")
    'FSO.CreateFolder(splitString(2) + "\AppData\Roaming\Local")
End If
```

Here you go man, this should work perfect, regards Daniel.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code part from my utilty for FSO:

```
dim ffso

Function GetFSO
    if not IsValidObject(ffso) then set ffso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set GetFSO = ffso
End Function

sub SureDirectoryExists(ADir)
    if ADir="" then exit sub
    if not GetFSO().FolderExists(ADir) then
        SureDirectoryExists ffso.GetParentFolderName(ADir)
        ffso.CreateFolder ADir
    end if
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will create all folders in the path parameter (string).

```
Public Function CheckCreateFolder(path)
    Dim TempPath As String
    Dim FSO
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    pos = 0
     While pos < Len(path)
        pos = InStr(pos + 1, path, "\")
        TempPath = Left(path, pos)
        If Not (FSO.FolderExists(TempPath)) Then
        FSO.CreateFolder (TempPath)
        End If
     Wend
    
End Function
```