# Creating a Folder After Macro Clears my Clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

When I paste after running my code, there is nothing in the Clipboard to paste.

1. Some code concatenates two cell values into a string.
2. That string goes to a Data object which is copied to the clipboard
3. The next bit of code opens a folder in a Windows Explorer window. I want to manually create the folder (CRTL+SHIFT+N) and paste the string as the name of the folder.

When I use F8 to step through the code, I can confirm that the value is copying to the clipboard properly.

But when I run the code with F5 and manually create the folder, there is nothing there to paste.

I am suspecting that there is something about the (CRTL+SHIFT+N) keystroke that clears the clipboard.

```
'Looking at the Sheet Name For The Hyperlink Lookup Later
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Submittals" Then
Dim SubName As String
Dim SubFldr As New MSForms.DataObject
LinkType = "Submittal Location"

'Joining the Cell Values to a string
SubName = Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & " " & Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value
MsgBox SubName
SubFldr.SetText Text:=SubName
SubFldr.PutInClipboard

'Looks up link address from elsewhere in the subroutine and stores it to a variable
Link = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Project, Range("Project_Table"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(LinkType, Range("Project_Table_Header"), 0) _
    , False)

'Opens the Explorer window
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=Link
```

It's at this point that I want to manually create a folder (CRTL+SHIFT+N) and paste the SubFldr value that should be in the clipboard.

If I paste in Notepad or else where before creating the folder, the value is there, and I can reuse it.

If I make the folder and then paste (my ultimate goal), there is nothing to paste.

It's likely obvious from my code that I know just enough to get myself into trouble. There are more efficient ways to do what I'm trying to do

Comment: Use `FSO` to create a folder if it doesn't exist then you can save to the location. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909365/check-if-folder-is-there-if-not-create-it-on-current-user-logged-in-vbs

Comment: Sending keystrokes is a dirty hack, there has got to be a better way.